# Localhost python multiple variable assignation

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I have a question. I try to understand some networking concepts, and I was playing with python.

I have a small question. Why

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6,socket.SOCK_STREAM) # this is always present
```

this

```
clientsocket,adress = s.accept()
```

is different than this?

```
clientsocket = s.accept()
adress = s.accept()
```

and I also have one more thing to mention. I used the debugger to check the differences between variables, and I found that *clientsocket* and *s* have the same attributes, but when I try to use *s* instead of *clientsocket* I get an error. I would love an explanation.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html):

> socket.accept()
>
> Accept a connection. The socket must be bound to an address and listening for connections. The return value is a **pair** (conn, address) where conn is a new socket object usable to send and receive data on the connection, and address is the address bound to the socket on the other end of the connection.

So, the socket.accept() returns a *pair* of values. If you use this form of an assignment:

```
clientsocket, address = s.accept()
```

you simultaneously assign both variables. It's like

```
temporary = s.accept()
clientsocket = temporary[0]
address = temporary[1]
```

but more efficient and readable. However, when you do

```
clientsocket = s.accept()
address = s.accept()
```

you call socket.accept() twice, so the clientsocket gets the socket from the first call, and address takes the address from the second call. Since the results of two different calls to socket.accept() are not related in any way the clientsocket and address now are not related either. If you make a web server and two clients will try to retrieve a page from you web server, then clientsocket will correspond to the communication channel with the first client, while address will contain the address of the second client. Chaos is guaranteed.

About your second question - again read the documentation:

> Accept a connection. The socket must be bound to an address and listening for connections. The return value is a pair (conn, address) where conn is a **new socket object** usable to send and receive data on the connection, and address is the address bound to the socket on the other end of the connection.

The original socket represents an object, which you bind to some port on your computer to accept incoming traffic. When the request for the connection arrives, a *new socket object* is created which will represent the newly created communication channel. The original socket can still be used to accept more connections. So the connection object returned by socket.accept() and the original socket itself are different objects.